# On the divergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{1+n^{2}\cdot cos^{2}(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence

On the forum quora.com I encountered the question how it can be shown that this series diverges which motivated me to investigate whether there is a $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n\cdot \left| cos(n) \right|\lt c$ holds for infinitely many natural numbers $n$ because this would imply $\frac{1}{1+n^{2}\cdot cos^{2}(n)}\geqslant \frac{1}{1+c^{2}}\gt 0$ for those $n$ so that this term cannot converge to $0$ for $n\to \infty $ which is necessary for the series to converge at all. Meanwhile I could prove that $c=10$ does the job (and any $c\gt 10$, of course). My proof is based on a nice theorem by the German mathematician Leopold Kronecker which dates back as early as 1884 (see e.g. Hardy & Wright: An Intrduction to the Theory of Numbers, Theorem 440): If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is irrational and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ are arbitrary then there exist a natural number $n\gt N$ and an integer $m$ satisfying $\left| n\cdot \alpha-m -\beta \right|\lt \frac{3}{n}$. I exploit this theorem for $\alpha=\pi$ and $\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus the question on Quora is settled but besides this I am now interested to find out the greatest lower bound $L$ of the set of all "admissible" real numbers $c$. $L=0$ is equivalent to the following statement: Given an arbitrary $\varepsilon\gt 0$, are there infinitely many natural numbers $n$ for which $n\cdot \left| cos(n) \right|\lt \varepsilon$ holds? I suspect that this is false but I cannot give a proof as yet. Can anybody else? So if $L\gt 0$, can you, let's say, determine $L$ up to 5 valid decimal digits?

Comment: Questions like this quickly get into discussions on the irrationality measure of $\pi$. That might be a good place to start https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html

Comment: From my proof I know that the set $S:=\left\{ c\in \mathbb{R\:|\:\left|n \cdot \pi- m -\frac{\pi}{2} \right|}\lt \frac{c}{m} for\: infinitely\: many \: m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is not empty because I have proved that $10\in S$. And now I want to determine $inf \:S$. I do not see how this is related to the irrationality measure of $\pi$.Can you give more detail please?

Comment: @QC_QAOA  I will explain the significance of the set $S$ (see my above comment) for my problem: If $c\in S$ then $\left| cos(m) \right|=\left| cos(n\cdot \pi -\frac{\pi}{2})-cos(m)  \right|\leqslant \left| (n\cdot \pi -\frac{\pi}{2})-m \right|\lt \frac{c}{m}$ for infinitely many $m\in \mathbb{N}$-